Error with training and loading ViT model
I am trying to train a ViT model and and save it to be used in another program. I am using the example of the vision transformer model for image classification provided on the Keras website as reference.
The model saves as a ".keras" file.
But I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/model.py:533, in Model.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    532 try:
--> 533     return cls(**config)
    534 except TypeError as e:

TypeError: ViTClassfier.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input_shape' and 'n_classes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:718, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    717 try:
--> 718     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    719 except TypeError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/model.py:535, in Model.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    534 except TypeError as e:
--> 535     raise TypeError(
    536         "Unable to revive model from config. When overriding "
    537         "the `get_config()` method, make sure that the "
    538         "returned config contains all items used as arguments "
    539         f"in the  constructor to {cls}, "
    540         "which is the default behavior. "
    541         "You can override this default behavior by defining a "
    542         "`from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify "
    543         "how to create an "
    544         f"instance of {cls.__name__} from its config.\n\n"
    545         f"Received config={config}\n\n"
    546         f"Error encountered during deserialization: {e}"
    547     )

TypeError: Unable to revive model from config. When overriding the `get_config()` method, make sure that the returned config contains all items used as arguments in the  constructor to <class '__main__.ViTClassfier'>, which is the default behavior. You can override this default behavior by defining a `from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify how to create an instance of ViTClassfier from its config.

Received config={'name': 'vi_t_classfier', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': {'module': 'keras', 'class_name': 'DTypePolicy', 'config': {'name': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': None}}

Error encountered during deserialization: ViTClassfier.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input_shape' and 'n_classes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 2
      1 from keras.models import load_model
----> 2 lm = load_model('ViT_on_100_epochs.keras')
      3 cfg2=model.get_config()
      4 print(cfg2)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:182, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    179         is_keras_zip = True
    181 if is_keras_zip or is_keras_dir:
--> 182     return saving_lib.load_model(
    183         filepath,
    184         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    185         compile=compile,
    186         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    187     )
    188 if str(filepath).endswith((".h5", ".hdf5")):
    189     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(
    190         filepath, custom_objects=custom_objects, compile=compile
    191     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:237, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    232     raise ValueError(
    233         "Invalid filename: expected a `.keras` extension. "
    234         f"Received: filepath={filepath}"
    235     )
    236 with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
--> 237     return _load_model_from_fileobj(
    238         f, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode
    239     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:314, in _load_model_from_fileobj(fileobj, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    311 with zf.open(_CONFIG_FILENAME, "r") as f:
    312     config_json = f.read()
--> 314 model = _model_from_config(
    315     config_json, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode
    316 )
    318 all_filenames = zf.namelist()
    319 weights_file_path = None

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:303, in _model_from_config(config_json, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    301 # Construct the model from the configuration file in the archive.
    302 with ObjectSharingScope():
--> 303     model = deserialize_keras_object(
    304         config_dict, custom_objects, safe_mode=safe_mode
    305     )
    306 return model

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:720, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    718     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    719 except TypeError as e:
--> 720     raise TypeError(
    721         f"{cls} could not be deserialized properly. Please"
    722         " ensure that components that are Python object"
    723         " instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by"
    724         " `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the"
    725         " model's `from_config()` method."
    726         f"\n\nconfig={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    727     )
    728 build_config = config.get("build_config", None)
    729 if build_config and not instance.built:

TypeError: <class '__main__.ViTClassfier'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': None, 'class_name': 'ViTClassfier', 'config': {'name': 'vi_t_classfier', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': {'module': 'keras', 'class_name': 'DTypePolicy', 'config': {'name': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': None}}, 'registered_name': 'Custom>ViTClassfier', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 128, 128, 3]}, 'compile_config': {'optimizer': {'module': 'keras.optimizers', 'class_name': 'Adam', 'config': {'name': 'adam', 'learning_rate': 0.0010000000474974513, 'weight_decay': None, 'clipnorm': None, 'global_clipnorm': None, 'clipvalue': None, 'use_ema': False, 'ema_momentum': 0.99, 'ema_overwrite_frequency': None, 'loss_scale_factor': None, 'gradient_accumulation_steps': None, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2': 0.999, 'epsilon': 1e-07, 'amsgrad': False}, 'registered_name': None}, 'loss': {'module': 'keras.losses', 'class_name': 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', 'config': {'name': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'reduction': 'sum_over_batch_size', 'from_logits': True, 'ignore_class': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'loss_weights': None, 'metrics': ['accuracy', {'module': None, 'class_name': 'BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy', 'config': {'name': 'balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy', 'dtype': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': 'BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy'}], 'weighted_metrics': None, 'run_eagerly': False, 'steps_per_execution': 1, 'jit_compile': False}}.

Exception encountered: Unable to revive model from config. When overriding the `get_config()` method, make sure that the returned config contains all items used as arguments in the  constructor to <class '__main__.ViTClassfier'>, which is the default behavior. You can override this default behavior by defining a `from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify how to create an instance of ViTClassfier from its config.

Received config={'name': 'vi_t_classfier', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': {'module': 'keras', 'class_name': 'DTypePolicy', 'config': {'name': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': None}}

Error encountered during deserialization: ViTClassfier.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input_shape' and 'n_classes'

I am unable to solve this when it is in the same python file.
Can someone tell me how can I handle this? Also, it seems like I have to copy over classes from the file to train the model to whichever python file that I want to load the model in. Is there a better approach to this?
Here is my code, I am using Kaggle for this:
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
print(keras.__version__)

class AttrDict(dict):
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__


def plot_grid_ds(ds, model=None, size=(3, 3), figsize=(10, 10)):
    from copy import copy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

    n = size[0] * size[1]
    ds_ = copy(ds)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    grid = ImageGrid(
        fig,
        111,
        nrows_ncols=size,
        axes_pad=0.3,
    )
    for X_batch, y_batch in ds_.unbatch().shuffle(n).batch(n).take(1):
        y_hat_batch = model.predict(X_batch).argmax(axis=-1) if model else y_batch
        for X, y, y_hat, ax in zip(X_batch, y_batch, y_hat_batch, grid):
            title = (
                f"{ds.class_names[y]} (true) - {ds.class_names[y_hat]} (pred)"
                if model
                else f"{ds.class_names[y]}"
            )
            ax.set_title(title)
            ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
            ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
            ax.imshow(X / 255, cmap="gray")
    return grid

class BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy(tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy):
    def __init__(self, name="balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy", dtype=None):
        super().__init__(name, dtype=dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_flat = y_true
        if y_true.shape.ndims == y_pred.shape.ndims:
            y_flat = tf.squeeze(y_flat, axis=[-1])
        y_true_int = tf.cast(y_flat, tf.int32)

        cls_counts = tf.math.bincount(y_true_int)
        cls_counts = tf.math.reciprocal_no_nan(tf.cast(cls_counts, self.dtype))
        weight = tf.gather(cls_counts, y_true_int)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weight)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import register_keras_serializable

class Patches(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size, **kwargs):
        super(Patches, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
        return patches

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class PatchEncoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, **kwargs):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )

    def call(self, patch):
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
        return encoded


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class ViTClassfier(tf.keras.models.Model):
    CONFIG = {
        "patch_size": 4, 
        "embedding_dim": 32,
        "n_heads": 2,
        "n_transformers": 1,
        "transformer_units": [64, 32],
        "transformer_dropout": 0.1,
        "mlp_units": [2048, 1024],
        "mlp_dropout": 0.1,
        #"input_shape": [128, 128, 3],
    }

    def __init__(self, input_shape, n_classes, config={}, **kwargs):
        super(ViTClassfier, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self._config = AttrDict(
            **{
                **self.CONFIG,
                **config,
                "input_shape": input_shape,
                "n_classes": n_classes,
            }
        )
        self._construct_model()

    def call(self, x):
        return self._model(x)

    def _construct_model(self):
        config = self._config

        num_patches = (config['input_shape'][0] // config['patch_size']) ** 2

        inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=config['input_shape'])

        patches = Patches(config['patch_size'])(inputs)
        # Encode patches.
        encoded_patches = PatchEncoder(num_patches, config['embedding_dim'])(patches)

        # Create multipletf.keras.layers of the Transformer block.
        for _ in range(config['n_transformers']):
            # Layer normalization 1.
            x1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
            # Create a multi-head attention layer.
            attention_output = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
                num_heads=config['n_heads'], key_dim=config['embedding_dim'], dropout=0.1
            )(x1, x1)
            # Skip connection 1.
            x2 = tf.keras.layers.Add()([attention_output, encoded_patches])
            # Layer normalization 2.
            x3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x2)
            # MLP.
            for units in config['transformer_units']:
                x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(x3)
                x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config['transformer_dropout'])(x3)

            # Skip connection 2.
            encoded_patches = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x3, x2])

        # Create a [batch_size, projection_dim] tensor.
        features = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
        features = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(features)
        features = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(features)
        # Add MLP.
        for units in config['mlp_units']:
            features = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(features)
            features = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config['mlp_dropout'])(features)
        # Classify outputs.
        logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(config['n_classes'])(features)
        # Create the Keras model.
        self._model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)

from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


path = Path("/kaggle/input/breast-ultrasound-images-dataset/Dataset_BUSI_with_GT")
img_as_jpg = list(path.glob(r"*/*.png"))

# Counts the number of each categories in the dataset
file_count = list(map(lambda x: os.path.split(os.path.split(x)[0])[1],img_as_jpg))
benign = file_count.count('benign')
malignant = file_count.count('malignant')
normal = file_count.count('normal')

train = pd.concat([pd.Series(img_as_jpg,name="image").apply(str),pd.Series(file_count, name="type")],axis=1)
train = train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

hparams = AttrDict(
    image_size=(128, 128, 3),
    n_classes=3,
    batch_size=64,
)

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory("/kaggle/input/breast-ultrasound-images-dataset/Dataset_BUSI_with_GT", image_size=hparams.image_size[:-1], batch_size=hparams.batch_size)
train_split = round(0.8 * ds.cardinality().numpy()) 
train_ds = ds.take(train_split); train_ds.class_names = ds.class_names
validation_ds = ds.skip(train_split); validation_ds.class_names = ds.class_names

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
    model = ViTClassfier(hparams.image_size, hparams.n_classes)
    
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=["accuracy", BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
    )

import time

start = time.time()

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=100, validation_data=validation_ds)
end = time.time()

model.save("ViT_on_100_epochs.keras")

from keras.models import load_model
lm = load_model('ViT_on_100_epochs.keras')


At which location in your code does the error happen?

Please [edit] your question and reduce your code to only essential parts, e.g. remove parts that are related to plotting or appear after the error. Thanks a lot.

The Error occurs at the end when loading the model. I will try to shorten it.
